# SQL Instance - Named and Unnamed at the same time?

Tags: sql-server

I just bumped into something I never saw before: I have an instance in this server that can be accessed by a name and without it as well.

I know we can have instances with empty names and then we enter only the server name, as simple as this:

**SERVERNAME**

And I'm used to named instances where we use this:

**SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME**

But I never saw an instance that can be accessed both ways.

What am I missing here?

[image: SQL Login]

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, if the named instance is explicitly set to run on port 1433 then the name isn't strictly required, also you can use client network utility to create aliases that let you fool client tools about what you're really connecting to...

Comment: when you to go sql server configuration manager, how are you seeing the instances ?